# How does a Cavalier fighter's Unwavering Mark feature interact with other "mark" abilities?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, mark

The [Cavalier fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Cavalier)'s Unwavering Mark feature (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 30) says:

> This effect ends early if you are incapacitated or you die, **or if someone else marks the creature**.

Does the word "marks" there only refer to other uses of Unwavering Mark, or does it apply to (for example) [*hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) as well?

Comment: Flipping through Xanathar's for an answer I also found Grave Domain's Path to the Grave is also a mark... Except its worded as a curse too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### To another use of Unwavering Mark.

The 5th edition doesn't have a *Mark* category of abilities like the 4th edition. If that was applicable would be written on the ability itself since there is no general guidelines.

A DM could rule that the *Mark* could end if another character with a similar ability like the UA Knight's *Implacable Mark*, but that would not be following the usual 5e design and would just be the preference of the DM. Either way, *Hunter's Mark* doesn't interact with it.

Comment: It is worth noting that the cavalier ability that I ask about is the official released version of the Knight/Implacable Mark. Not that it invalidates anything about your point.

Comment: Would it be worth pointing out the fact that one is an ability and the other a spell as well?

Answer (score 2):

Hunter's Mark says:

> "You choose a creature you can see within range and mystically mark it as your quarry."

Mark - the combat options on Page 271 of Dungeon Master's Guide.

> "When a creature makes a melee attack, it can also mark its target.
> Until the end of the attacker's next turn, any opportunity attack it
> makes against the marked target has advantage. The opportunity attack
> doesn't expend the attackers reaction, but the attacker can't make the
> attack if anything, such as the incapacitated condition or the
> shocking grasp spell, is preventing it from taking reactions. The
> attacker is limited to one opportunity attack per turn."

Hunter's Mark, Unwavering Mark, and Mark (combat option) all do say they do a mark. It will come down to how your DM interprets all the marks and if the others clash with the Cavalier ability.